Video Driver for Dell Precision 5690 with Nvidia RTX 3500 running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Having difficulties finding the correct video driver for a Dell Precision 5690 with a NVIDIA RTX 3500 graphics card on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Many of the nvidia drivers do not work. sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall will pull the 535 driver, which provides a black screen after reboot. Another reliable driver we have found in the past is the 470 one but for some reason external monitors do not work with this and remain black. Curious if anyone has found a correct nvidia driver that isn't faulty for this model of laptop running Ubuntu 22? Everything works as expected if I load windows on it. Bios is updated and fresh install of Ubuntu. Can't think of anything else to look at
Thanks

Updating the kernel from version 6.5.0-41 to 6.5.0-44 allowed the nvidia 535 video driver to work as expected
